# Node Express SameSite Not Recognised by Browsers

Tags: node.js, express

I am unable to prevent this warning, despite the fact that I have set node express cookie.

```
Cookie “connect.sid” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite


{
  store: sessionStore, 
  resave: false, 
  saveUninitialized: true,
  rolling: false,
  secret: 'mysecret', 
  cookie:{
    maxAge    : 60000 * $.idlemin,
    samesite  : 'secure'
  }
}
```

I have also tried, 'strict' and true and they appear to make no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this:

```
  cookie:{
    maxAge    : 60000 * $.idlemin,
    SameSite  : true
  }
```